# Woocommerce Bookings Time slots end time

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-bookings

I am working on a room rental website that uses Wordpress with Woocommerce Bookings. Some of my rooms can be rented with a predetermined duration of 4 hours only.

But when a user clicks on a date to check whether there are any available time slots left, he only sees the start of the time slot and not the end. This means, that the user doesn't know when the time slot he/she books will be over/for how long he will be able to use the room.

For further explanation, here is an image to show the issue. In this example, the user only sees that the start of the first available time slot is at 13:00 but not when it will end.

[image]

Is there any way to add the end time to the time slot?
I appreciate any help :)

Thanks,
Jakob

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution ? Thank you